# Focusing Controls Inside RichTextboxes

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, controls, richtextbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Components Inside Textbox/RichTextbox in DotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027633/components-inside-textbox-richtextbox-in-dotnet)

I have a textbox inside of my RichTextbox control. (The texboxt contains certain expressions that cannot otherwise be done in richtextbox itself.)  I am having trouble focusing/navigating into the element when the caret is adjacent to the object.  The caret is just skipping over the object.  Is there any way to notice the object and focus on to it (in this case focus into the textbox)?

Actually, I should be more specific, the 'textbox' is actually a UserControl that can contain multiple texboxes and other symbols so it's not just a simple wpf 'textbox'.  But essentially it behaves like a textbox.

Thanks.

```
        <RichTextBox Name="rtb" Grid.Row="1" >
        <ed:EnabledFlowDoc x:Name="efdMath" TextBlock.BaselineOffset="-10"
                           FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
            <Paragraph TextBlock.BaselineOffset="10" TextInput="Paragraph_TextInput_1">
                Text . . .
                <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBox />
                </InlineUIContainer>
                <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBox />
                </InlineUIContainer>

            </Paragraph>
        </ed:EnabledFlowDoc>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Sure, if it helps . . . let me do it now.

Comment: if someone can delete this post that would be awesome (i've already answered this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function I was looking for is this . . .

```
RichTextBox.CaretPosition.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection Direction)
```

for more information, look at my newer post since i cannot delete this old post . . .

[Components Inside Textbox/RichTextbox in DotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027633/components-inside-textbox-richtextbox-in-dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `IsDocumentEnabled="True"` Property of RichTextBox.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done by override IsEnabledCore property of FlowDocument:

```
class EnabledFlowDoc : FlowDocument
{
    protected override bool IsEnabledCore
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

find this solution [here](http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/01/18/When-I-add-Controls-to-a-WPF-RichTextBox-They-Are-Always-Disabled-How-can-I-change-that.aspx)

Comment: no i have the objects inside of the flow documents already. i'm talking about getting the cursor to focus in when you are adjacent to the object . . .