# Components Inside Textbox/RichTextbox in DotNet

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am working with a textbox/richtextbox component in WPF and I need to import additional textboxes into it.  Currently, I use a RichTextbox control that inserts additional custom textboxes into (they are necessary since it is an expression that cannot otherwise be done).  The problem I'm having is I need to focus into the the textbox when the cursor is adjacent to the textbox inside of the richtexbox.  It seems to ignore the component and skip over it.  Does anyone else have a solution to this?

I can't seem to get any control to the cursor or components inside of the RichTexbox in WPF.

Comment: wow. this place is dead compared to overflow . . . or maybe cuz it's christmas eve?

Comment: You should try to use a [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485533/wpf-richtextbox-seamless-textboxes-as-inlineuicontainers) and the final solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIComponent that is embedded inside my RichTextBox is actually a digit which contains 3 TextBoxes (base, superscript, and subscript).  The problem I had was that the cursor couldn't focus into the digit component.

The function I was looking for is this . . .

```
RichTextBox.CaretPosition.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection Direction)
```

here is my code . . .

```
public class MathRichTextbox : RichTextBox
{
    public MathRichTextbox()
    {
        this.PreviewKeyDown += MathRichTextbox_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    void MathRichTextbox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Digit expr = null;

        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
                expr = findAdjacentMathDigits(LogicalDirection.Backward);
                break;

            case Key.Right:
                expr = findAdjacentMathDigits(LogicalDirection.Forward);                    
                break;
        }

        if (expr != null)
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new ThreadStart(() => expr.FocusBase()),
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input, null);
    }

    private Digit findAdjacentMathDigits(LogicalDirection direction)
    {
        Digit expr = null;

        if (Selection.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            DependencyObject dpObj = CaretPosition.GetAdjacentElement(
                direction);

            // is it contained in BlockUIContainer?
            expr = CaretPosition.GetAdjacentElement(
                direction) as Digit;

            // is it onctained in a InlineUIContainer?
            if (expr == null)
            {
                InlineUIContainer uiWrapper =
                    CaretPosition.GetAdjacentElement(
                    direction) as InlineUIContainer;

                if (uiWrapper != null)
                    expr = uiWrapper.Child as Digit;
            }

        }

        return expr;
    }

}
```

Comment: nice; shouldn't you set `e.Handled = true?`

Comment: Of course you might find `RichTextBox.SelectionCharOffset` property intresting.

Comment: I may in the future, but I dont want to interrupt the user if it doesn't find anything and if it does, it will focus on its own. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I actually dontk now how to use that property (RichTextBox.SelectionCharOffset) yet, but i will definitely study that more.

Comment: also i found this website that wrote a really nice project that wrote about tokenizing text, you may be interested http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you should try to use a [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead.

A `Run` is not much different from a TextBox. Let me give you an example:

You want to add this string "This is an example" at the beginning of a `Paragraph` in a RichTextBox:

```
Paragraph _para //I assume you have this
TextPointer pointer=_para.ContentStart;
Run run=new Run("This is an example",pointer);
```

That's it. You can set FontSize, FontFamily and ... other properties like a `TextBox`.

```
run.Foregroung=Brushes.Red;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ya dude, your pointers/links really help. i think i might have an effective solution. i'll share with you soon if it works.